Why are the HAC (Newey-West) standard errors smaller than the ordinary standard errors in my regression?
I used time series to perform a regression, and then I conducted the Breusch-Godfrey (BG) test and the White test. The test results indicated the presence of both autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity. Therefore, I chose to use HAC (Newey-West) standard errors for my analysis. I was astonished to find that the HAC (Newey-West) standard errors are smaller than the ordinary standard errors. Why is this the case? In this situation, which standard errors should I use?

Another possible duplicate target is the one linked by Christoph Hanck: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/654832/what-does-it-mean-when-newey-west-standard-errors-are-much-larger-than-other-typ/654841#654841

Here is a similar example for HC estimators that only allow for heteroskedasticity, not serial correlation as does HAC: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/627057/why-does-heteroskedasticity-not-affect-r2-and-why-does-it-make-estimated-regr/627136#627136

The issue can arise under negative serial correlation, see What does it mean when newey-west standard errors are much larger than other types of standard errors for the respective formulae. There, I deal with the situation in which the AR coefficient is large (possibly close to one). Here, we should rather try a negative AR coefficient, e.g.
library(sandwich)
n <- 1e6
    
phi <- -0.5
y <- arima.sim(list(ar=phi), n)
    
# standard variance estimators, scaled with n so that they do not plim to zero
1/(1-phi^2) # what lm's formula estimates, i.e. 4/3
n*summary(lm(y~1))$coef[1,2]^2 #very close to 4/3 for large n
var(y)      # alternatively
     
n*lrvar(y, type="Newey-West", prewhite=F, adjust=F) 
# close to theoretical long-run variance of an AR(1), i.e.
1/(1-phi)^2 # 1/2.25

As to which to prefer, when a robust estimator and a nonrobust estimator differ, at least in large samples, I would tend to favor the robust one. This is because, if we were in a situation in which the nonrobust one is also valid, the robust one typically estimates the same target, so that they should then not differ too much (for small $n$ things may be a little different, as the nonrobust one often is more efficient). Hence, if they differ a lot, this points to the nonrobust one not being valid.
EDIT: Here is a little simulation to investigate the merits of the strategy of using the larger of the robust and conventional standard error in forming the t-statistic, in the context of HC (so "only" heteroskedasticity consistency) versus standard OLS s.e.s. (cf. the comments below).
It turns out the conservativeness I expected there does not quite show: under homoskedasticity, the two standard errors barely differ, so that taking their max does not change the distribution. Under types of heteroskedasticity where the robust standard errors are practically always larger, the "correct" ones "win", such that the distribution of the t-statistic with the maximum of the s.e.s in the denominator boils down to the one using the robust standard errors.
Hence, if anything we are left with a heteroskedastic situation in which the correct robust standard errors are smaller than the nonrobust ones, as in Why does heteroskedasticity not affect $R^2$ and why does it make estimated regression more statistically significant?, such that using the larger ones would amount to using the "wrong" nonrobust one.
However, the exercise below gives rejection rates of close to 5% based on robust s.e.s (as should be the case) and around 4.3% for the maximum s.e. strategy, so not a large difference.
library(sandwich)
    
n <- 5000
    
max.tstat <- function(n){
  # x <- rnorm(n)
  # x <- runif(n, -.1, .1)
  # # u <- rnorm(n)
  # u <- x*rnorm(n) # here we actually have heteroskedasticity, then robust SEs almost always larger, so that it boils down to standard robust t statistic
  # y <- u
      
# DGP from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657795/why-are-the-hac-newey-west-standard-errors-smaller-than-the-ordinary-standard/657814#657814:
  n0 <- 1/4*n
  n1 <- 3/4*n
      
  y <- c(rnorm(n0, sd=1), rnorm(n1, sd=1.05))  # i.e. more variance when dummy=1
  x <- c(rep(0, n0), rep(1,n1)) # a dummy regressor
      
  reg <- lm(y~x)
  est.coeff <- summary(reg)$coefficients[2,1]
  conv.se <- summary(reg)$coefficients[2,2]
  rob.se <- sqrt(vcovHC(reg, "HC1")[2,2])
  t.statmax <- est.coeff/max(c(conv.se, rob.se))
  t.statrob <- est.coeff/rob.se
      
  return(c(t.statmax, t.statrob, conv.se, rob.se))
}
    
tstats <- replicate(10000, max.tstat(n))
    
plot(density(tstats[1,]), col="lightgreen", lwd=2)
lines(density(tstats[2,]), lwd=2, col="darkblue")
x <- seq(-3, 3, by=.1)
lines(x, dnorm(x), lwd=2, col="darkred")
    
summary(tstats[3,])       # nonrobust s.e.s, here slightly *larger* than...
summary(tstats[4,])       # ...robust s.e.s
  
mean(abs(tstats[1,])>qnorm(.975)) # hence, rejection rate based on maximum s.e.s slightly lower than...

mean(abs(tstats[2,])>qnorm(.975)) # ...rejection rate based on robust s.e.s, but not by much (see text)
    
qqplot(tstats[3,], tstats[4,], xlim=c(0.031, 0.036), ylim=c(0.031, 0.036), ylab="robust", xlab="nonrobust")    # robust s.e.s
abline(a=0, b=1)

The qq plot shows that the conventional standard errors tend to be a little larger than the robust ones here:

Things might be different in my initial HAC example in which the HAC standard errors are substantially smaller.

"for small $n$ things may be a little different". I thinks this needs a little elaborating. Here's an example where specifically Newey-West is way off for the F-Statistic of $n = 100$ and $20$ variables, although it's not as extreme on the level of individual coefficients: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/654917/341520

I agree, but elaborating is not necessarily easy as - your example is a good one - characterizing "small" is notoriously difficult, e.g. because as you say, it also depends on things like the number of coefficients

Fair enough. Xu Yangs sampler maybe isn't neccesarily small but definitely isn't large. Would you agree with my advice to, in that situation, use the larger SE and, if you can find evidence of negative auto-correlation, Newey West as a hopeful alternative?

As a pragmatic device, using the larger probably is not too bad, although it must inevitably imply some conservativeness - i.e., when you aim to test at 5%, you no longer will uniformly, as you will deflate t-statistics by something which is at least as large as the "right" SEs given respective assumptions. As to using NW when there is evidence for negative serial correlation, I would again say that this is sort of reasonable, although one can again probably make a similar case to the previous point, now that this is some kind of pretesting which may cause issues.

But clearly, it is much easier to explain what may go wrong in a complex world than to give guidance as to how to proceed, so some pragmatism may be inevitable as practical situations more often than not do not do us the favor of fitting into neat textbook setups.

Thank you. very interesting!

Christopher Hancks answer is an option. Another option would be the following:
Robust standard errors are biased towards 0, which effects them a lot if sample sizes are small. What's your ratio of sample size to coefficients?
Previous answers about this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38569/341520
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590851/341520
Simulations by me: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/654917/341520


My sample size is 147. Thanks your answers

@XuYang Then the nonrobust SE is probably more reliable and must be reported. If you have evidence for negative auto-correlation, you might report Newey-West as a hopeful alternative.
